# BroadcastReceiver monitoring for a specific USB device attached

Tags: android, usb, broadcast, intentfilter

I have an activity that starts when a specific USB device is attached, as specified in a device filter file, which works great:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.mycompany.DerpApp.MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"  />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
        </activity>
```

I also have a service where I want to monitor for connect and disconnect. I have BroadcastReceivers wired up, and they fire upon device attach and detach. However, I want these broadcast receivers to trigger when only a device as specified in my device_filter.xml is attached/detached.

```
m_usbDisconnectReceiver = new UsbDisconnectReceiver();
registerReceiver(m_usbDisconnectReceiver, new IntentFilter(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED));

m_usbConnectReceiver = new UsbConnectReceiver();
registerReceiver(m_usbConnectReceiver, new IntentFilter(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED));
```

I am unsure of how to attach my device_filter file to the programatically created Broadcast Receiver. Is there something I can do in the IntentFilter for this? I think that the Intent that is provided to the onReceive() has a UsbDevice as one of its extras, but it would be best if I could filter it out so the event doesn't fire. And if that's not possible, how can I check to see if the UsbDevice is a part of my device_filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely have to create your BroadcastReceiver programatically, then you need to filter the devices programatically as well.

Try this:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    if (intent.getAction().equals(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED))
    {
        UsbDevice d = (UsbDevice)
            intent.getExtras().get(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);

       if (d.getVendorId() == MY_VENDOR_ID && d.getDeviceId() == MY_DEVICE_ID)
       {
              // Your code here
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I define a BroadcastReceiver for a service, or just for the entire application?

Comment: What do you mean by "for a service"? Do you mean you want the service to be notified when the broadcast receiver onReceive is triggered? If so, you can bind to that service inside onReceive and deliver whatever data you want to process on the service.

Comment: I mean that a Service owns and registers the Bro. Receiver.

Comment: Absolutely. You can either declare your broadcast receiver in the android manifest, in this case android will create it for you. Or you can create a static inner class extending BroadcastReceiver inside your service and register it dynamically with registerReceiver().